# Problem acquiring data on esp32 for geiger counter

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32

I bought the same boards used in [this](https://youtu.be/K28Az3-gV7E) video on Youtube (the componts are [THIS](https://it.banggood.com/Geekcreit-Assembled-DIY-Geiger-Counter-Kit-Module-Miller-Tube-GM-Tube-Nuclear-Radiation-Detector-Geekcreit-for-Arduino-products-that-work-with-official-Arduino-boards-p-1136883.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CZ) geiger counter (that I am pretty sure its working, the tiks on the speacker are coerent) and [THIS](https://it.banggood.com/ESP32-OLED-Module-ESP32-OLED-WiFi-bluetooth-Dual-ESP-32-ESP-32S-ESP8266-p-1148119.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=UK) esp (I don't know if is here the problem or in the code), I loaded the arduino code into the esp32 board, but the display remains stuck on "Measuring". It connects correctly to the ThingSpeak channel, but always linearly increasing measurements. The number grows continuously (view the attached image). I tried to insert some currentMillis and previousMillis println. Both variables are always 0 in the serial monitor.
So I tried adding currentMillis = millis (); at the beginning of the loop (), at this point the display has finally shown "radioactivity" with the usual increasing numbers. Even if the card is disconnected from the geiger counter, the data are the same and always increasing. How can I solve it?

[image]

```
#define PRINT_DEBUG_MESSAGES

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <IFTTTMaker.h>
#include <ThingSpeak.h>
#include <SSD1306.h>
//#include <credentials.h> // or define mySSID and myPASSWORD and THINGSPEAK_API_KEY

#define LOG_PERIOD 20000 //Logging period in milliseconds
#define MINUTE_PERIOD 60000
#define WIFI_TIMEOUT_DEF 30
#define PERIODE_THINKSPEAK 20000

#ifndef CREDENTIALS
// WLAN
#define mySSID ""
#define myPASSWORD ""

//IFTT
#define IFTTT_KEY "......."

// Thingspeak
#define SECRET_CH_ID 000000      // replace 0000000 with your channel number
#define SECRET_WRITE_APIKEY "XYZ"   // replace XYZ with your channel write API Key

#endif

// IFTTT
#define EVENT_NAME "Radioactivity" // Name of your event name, set when you are creating the applet


IPAddress ip;

WiFiClient client;

WiFiClientSecure secure_client;
IFTTTMaker ifttt(IFTTT_KEY, secure_client);
SSD1306  display(0x3c, 5, 4);

volatile unsigned long counts = 0;                       // Tube events
unsigned long cpm = 0;                                   // CPM
unsigned long previousMillis;                            // Time measurement
const int inputPin = 7;
unsigned int thirds = 0;
unsigned long minutes = 1;
unsigned long start = 0;
unsigned long entryThingspeak;
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

unsigned long myChannelNumber = SECRET_CH_ID;
const char * myWriteAPIKey = SECRET_WRITE_APIKEY;

#define LOG_PERIOD 20000 //Logging period in milliseconds
#define MINUTE_PERIOD 60000

void ISR_impulse() { // Captures count of events from Geiger counter board
  counts++;
}

void displayInit() {
  display.init();
  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
}

void displayInt(int dispInt, int x, int y) {
  display.setColor(WHITE);
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
  display.drawString(x, y, String(dispInt));
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display.display();
}

void displayString(String dispString, int x, int y) {
  display.setColor(WHITE);
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER);
  display.drawString(x, y, dispString);
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
  display.display();
}


/****reset***/
void software_Reset() // Restarts program from beginning but does not reset the peripherals and registers
{
  Serial.print("resetting");
  esp_restart();
}


void IFTTT(String event, int postValue) {
  if (ifttt.triggerEvent(EVENT_NAME, String(postValue))) {
    Serial.println("Successfully sent to IFTTT");
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("IFTTT failed!");
  }
}

void postThingspeak( int value) {
  // Write to ThingSpeak. There are up to 8 fields in a channel, allowing you to store up to 8 different
  // pieces of information in a channel.  Here, we write to field 1.
  int x = ThingSpeak.writeField(myChannelNumber, 1, value, myWriteAPIKey);
  if (x == 200) {
    Serial.println("Channel update successful.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Problem updating channel. HTTP error code " + String(x));
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  displayInit();
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);  // Initialize ThingSpeak
  displayString("Welcome", 64, 15);
  Serial.println("Connecting to Wi-Fi");

  WiFi.begin(mySSID, myPASSWORD);

  int wifi_loops = 0;
  int wifi_timeout = WIFI_TIMEOUT_DEF;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    wifi_loops++;
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
    if (wifi_loops > wifi_timeout)
    {
      software_Reset();
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Wi-Fi Connected");
  display.clear();
  displayString("Measuring", 64, 15);
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);                                                // Set pin for capturing Tube events
  interrupts();                                                            // Enable interrupts
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(inputPin), ISR_impulse, FALLING); // Define interrupt on falling edge
  unsigned long clock1 = millis();
  start = clock1;
}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    software_Reset();
  }

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis > LOG_PERIOD) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    cpm = counts * MINUTE_PERIOD / LOG_PERIOD;
    //cpm=105;
    counts = 0;
    display.clear();
    displayString("Radioactivity", 64, 0);
    displayInt(cpm, 64, 30);
    if (cpm > 100 ) IFTTT( EVENT_NAME, cpm);
  }
  // Serial.print("minutes: ");
  // Serial.println(String(minutes));

  //cpm = counts * MINUTE_PERIOD / LOG_PERIOD; this is just counts times 3 so:

  cpm = counts / minutes;


  if (millis() - entryThingspeak > PERIODE_THINKSPEAK) {
    Serial.print("Total clicks since start: ");
    Serial.println(String(counts));
    Serial.print("Rolling CPM: ");
    Serial.println(String(cpm));
    postThingspeak(cpm);
    entryThingspeak = millis();
  }

  //    if ( thirds > 2) {
  //      counts = 0;
  //      thirds = 0;
  //    }
}
```

This is based on [this](https://github.com/SensorsIot/Geiger-Counter-RadiationD-v1.1-CAJOE-) work on GITHUB

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone has the exact setup you are using. Thus, mostlikely there is some legwork you have to do yourself. Did you try replacing the sensor with e.g. a button or hotwire so that you can manually tic it?

Comment: You need a critical section for the code in loop that accesses counts.  What if an interrupt occurred in the middle of reading that variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your code never updates the value of currentMillis. You set it equal to millis at global scope, likely before init is called and before millis even has a value and then you just leave it with that value. You're not telling that variable to call millis every time, you're just giving it the value of millis at that one instant. You need a line in loop to update that variable.

Because of that, this section never runs:

```
if (currentMillis - previousMillis > LOG_PERIOD) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    cpm = counts * MINUTE_PERIOD / LOG_PERIOD;
    //cpm=105;
    counts = 0;
    display.clear();
    displayString("Radioactivity", 64, 0);
    displayInt(cpm, 64, 30);
    if (cpm > 100 ) IFTTT( EVENT_NAME, cpm);
  }
```

and counts never gets set back to 0.  That's why you see an ever increasing number.

You're also using this minutes variable as if it will count something, but you never add to it.  So it just stays at 1 forever as far as I can tell.